# Video file upload on MAC SAFARI using REST + JQuery Ajax gives 'The 500 Internal Server Error'

Tags: mac-os-x, jquery-ajax

I am trying to upload the Video file from MAC SAFARI (OS:MAC) in SharePoint 2013 (on prem) Document Library using REST + JQuery.AJAX which gives The 500 Internal Server Error.

My SharePoint page contains below rest query like:
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')

which I post to SharePoint server using jquery.ajax method

My JQuery version is 1.9.x

**note:** same code works with other browsers and I am able to upload the videos file successfully.

Please help.

Comment: Can you successfully use REST for any other operations like getting data?

Comment: Yes same code works well in other browsers in Win + Mac but it fails with 500 error in Safari in Mac (didn't​ test it with Safari in Win) so there shouldn't be issue with code but some​thing is going wrong with Safari